# How to intentionally define an "empty interface" in typescript

Tags: typescript, interface

TypeScript allows checking for checking unknown properties. The following

```
interface MyInterface {
  key: string
}

const myVar: MyInterface = {
  asda: 'asdfadf'
}
```

will fails with

> Type '{ asda: string; }' is not assignable to type 'MyInterface'.
>   Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'asda' does not
>   exist in type 'MyInterface'.

However, this statement will compile without any issue. [Empty interface will accept any value](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8032)

```
interface EmptyInterface {
}

const myVar: EmptyInterface = {
  asda: 'asdfadf'
}
```

However, what if I actually want to define type for an empty object that may not have **any** properties? How can I accomplish that in typescript?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To define an interface that never has any members, you can define an indexer that returns `never`

```
interface None { [n: string]: never } 
// OK
let d2 : None = {

}
let d3 : None = {
    x: "" // error
}
```

Comment: Not quite, you still can have properties initialized in a variable declared as `None` like this: `interface None { [n: string]: never } ; function f(): never { throw new Error(); } ; const myVar: None = {  q: f() }`. But for all practical purposes `never` indexer is good enough.

Comment: @artem ok, yes if you have something that returns never you can assign that into a property, but if it just returns never it will always be a runtime error anyway I think.  I am thinking of a solution that covers this as well, I will update if I come up with anything :)